# laravel file_get_contents('php://input') not working

Tags: php, laravel, http

I've searched for answers on this issue but i can't seem to find any solution.
I am trying to get response from an api service my application is consuming.
 On every successful transaction, the api will push a POST notification to any url i provide with details of the transaction. I found out that only get requests go through. However, if i route the request through the public folder, it seem to work fine.
Is there any way to get file_get_contents('php://input') work using POST route controller in laravel?

Here is a sample of my code:

ApiController.php

```
public function recieve_payment(Request $request){
    $res = file_get_contents('php://input');
    if (!empty($res)) {
        // insert values of $res to database
    }
}
```

routes/web.php

```
Route::post('/recieve', 'ApiController@recieve_payment');
```

Comment: You don't need `php://input` it will be in `$request->getContent()`, though you first need to find out whether the callback is sending to that controller. Something we cant help with.

Comment: thank you @LawrenceCherone let me see if it solves the problem

Comment: @LawrenceCherone POST requests do not go through at all even with the -curl command.

Comment: `However, if i route the request through the public folder` So an external request can't post to a "private" area ( I don't use laravel ). But that seems like reasonable behaviour.  Also what you are referring to `push a POST notification to any url i provide` is called a `web hook`

Comment: You also replace `file_get_contents('php://input')` with `$request->getContent()` . [View Source here](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/7365c360e3aad973880fdb65e43f1ec4b04252e9/Request.php#L1521)

Answer (score 8):

use `$request->getContent()`

[laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/access-raw-phpinput?page=1&replyId=67540).

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read how to [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I figured to exclude the URI from CSRF protection

```
protected $except = [
    'stripe/*',
];
```

That small piece of code saved me hours literally.

Comment: Doc about this can be found here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris, for anyone wondering.

Answer (score 2):

Place your route in routes/api.php instead of routes/web.php. routes/api.php has  CSRF disabled.

routes/api.php

```
Route::post('/recieve', 'ApiController@recieve_payment');
```

Your webhook URL will now be:

**BASE_URL/api/receive**

Also, you don't need to use:

```
$res = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

You can use:

```
$res = $request->all();
```

Comment: I guess `$request->getContent()` would be more correct way. [View Source here](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/7365c360e3aad973880fdb65e43f1ec4b04252e9/Request.php#L1521)